# How do I set up DBX connection pooling in code?

Tags: delphi, connection-pooling, delphi-xe, dbexpress

I've got Delphi XE Professional.  It comes with a fair amount of DBX stuff, including the `DBXPool` unit that contains the connection pooling support, but it doesn't have the full DBX support that comes in XE Enterprise.  In particular, a lot of the design-time support isn't there.

I don't particularly mind that. I've been able to do all the stuff I've needed without it, up until I needed connection pooling.  Now I'm trying to get that to work and I can't quite figure out how to make it work.  I can add `DBXPool` to my program and verify that it initializes, but then when I start making database requests, `TDBXPoolConnection.Create` is never called.

Here's my setup code for the connection, in the BeforeConnect event handler.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to get it right?

```
procedure TMyDataModule.connectionBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
   connection.DriverName := 'Firebird';
   connection.Params.Values['User_Name'] := FUserName;
   connection.Params.Values['Password'] := FPassword;
   connection.Params.Values['Database'] := FDatabasePath;
   connection.Params.Values['ServerCharSet'] := 'UTF8';
   connection.Params.values['DelegateName'] := 'DBXPool';
   connection.Params.values['DelegateConnection.MaxConnections'] := '32';
end;
```

**EDIT:** In case anyone comes across this in the future and has the same problem, here's how I had to set it up to make it work right.  Instead of the last two lines above,

```
connection.Params.values['DelegateConnection'] := 'DBXPoolConnection';
connection.Params.values['DBXPoolConnection.DriverName'] := 'DBXPool';
connection.Params.values['DBXPoolConnection.MaxConnections'] := '32';
```

Thanks to Sertac for putting me on the right course!

Comment: Is it possible that while the unit ships with XE pro, it isn't functional (because the DBX libraries/dlls don't enable this feature in this SKU?)

Comment: I've never done antying similar but from what I'v read I recall a "DelegateConnection" parameter. [Here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connection_Pooling_%28Delegate_Drivers_tutorial%29) it says it must be assigned 'DBXPoolConnection'.

Comment: @Sertac: Aha! That's what I was missing.  I'd read that, but I wasn't quite sure what parts applied to where.  I've got it working now. Thanks!  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mason what Firebird driver are you using? I was under the impression that the DBX driver for Firebird wasn't supported in the Professional version... You had to get the Enterprise or higer for that driver.

Comment: @CapeCodGunny: The driver produced by Chau Chee Yang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `DBXPoolConnection` to `DelegateConnection` parameter.

See: [Connection Pooling](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connection_Pooling_%28Delegate_Drivers_tutorial%29).