# Firebird database connection set with TIBConnectionBroker Component

Tags: database, delphi, firebird

Does anyone know of any database component sets for connection to [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org) database's with a component similar to the `TIBXConnectionBroker` in the IBX connection Set?

I know the IBX can connect to Firebird as well but they are drifting further and further apart so i need to make the switch.

Im using Delphi XE2

Comment: what is so special of IBX Connection Broker ? there are a lot of components, offering IB/FB connectivity, what exactly special do you need ? As of now, the question just asks for giving a list of access libraries.

Comment: No i am looking specifically for a library that has a component like the TIBConnectionBroker.

That component i find very useful because it maintains a pooled set of connections that can be called upon.

Its easier that creating a TIBDatabase every time you need one and its better than having lots of simultaneous connections to the database I.E. just grab a connection when you need it and release it when you are done

Comment: FireDAC pools them: http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Multi_Threading.html and DBExpress do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461492/ and IBDAC/UniDAC http://connect.remobjects.com/discussion/732/ Forums also say it is half-done in dbGO/ADO  There are also people who just implement the poool themselves: http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2009/02/building-connection-pool.html http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=15946.0